# SELECT statement with sqlsrv_query not returning results

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I have the following SELECT statement that is 'working' on the SQL Server query tool and returns rows. But, when I run it on PHP, it does not return any rows. I know the connection and the settings are working as when I create a simple query such as "SELECT * from ..." that works. here is my code.

```
$tsql = "SELECT  [d].[Device_Type_Name],
           [a].[Company_ID] AS [Alliance],
           [a].[Device_Address]
           FROM [dbo].[AL_LKP_User_Device] AS [a]
           INNER JOIN [dbo].[AL_LKP_User] AS [b]
           ON [a].[Login_ID] = [b].[Login_ID]
           INNER JOIN [dbo].[AL_LKP_NOTIFICATION_MASTER_LOG] AS [c]
           ON [b].[Login_ID] = [c].[Login_ID]
           INNER JOIN [dbo].[AL_LKP_Device_Type] AS [d]
           ON [a].[Device_Type_ID] = [d].[Device_Type_ID]";

$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql);
    if( !$stmt )
    {
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }

    $rows = sqlsrv_has_rows($stmt);
     if ($rows === true)
          echo "There are rows. <br />";
       else
      echo "There are no rows. <br />";
```

I keep getting the there are no rows when there are actually rows there. Anything that I need to change in the SQL statement??

Comment: `sqlsrv_has_rows` can return false if there is no rows, OR if an error occured, which could be the case here. Are you sure that the connection is working ? What if you try a simple select from one table ?

Comment: Yes, the connection is working. If I do a simple "SELECT * FROM [dbo].[AL_LKP_User_Device]" that works and returns results.

Comment: you should directly run your script (like sql). Then, you will see actual result.

Comment: @Thiha - How do I directly run my script??

Comment: @Hari S - Just assume you using mysql phpmyadmin. In your sql view and run this script, then you will see result and you can tack easily in sql view. I don't know sqlsrv IDE. Anyway, you can also run with windows command or Linux terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your identical operator(===) to equal operator(==).
Your $rows should actually contain values and you can test that by doing

```
print_r($rows)
```

or

```
vardump($rows)
```

I tested this:

```
$rows = array(1=>"a",2=>"b");
if ($rows === true)
echo "There are rows. <br />";
else
echo "There are no rows. <br />";
```

This does return "There are no rows" but if you change "===" to "==", you should be getting the "There are rows" answer.

`1 == 1` is true
`1 === '1'` is not true (left val is an integer, the other is a string)
`1 == '1'` is true (disregards variable type)

I hope this helps.